# Laravel collection returning duplicate

Tags: laravel, eloquent

Hi I am trying to return a Users Schedule where greater than or equal to todays date, or if that schedule contains a relation (ScheduledYard) that is not complete:

```php
$schedules = Auth::user()
        ->schedules()
        ->where('due_at', '>=' , Carbon::now())
        ->orWhereHas('scheduledYards', function ($query) {
            $query->where('completed', false);
        })->get();
    $schedules = $schedules->sortBy('due_at');
    return ScheduleResource::collection($schedules);
```

This works perfectly fine, but for some reason it is duplicating this for each user it is attached to. i.e if 3 users have this schedule then it is returned 3 times for the Authenticated user.

User Model:

```php
public function schedules()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\Schedule');
}
```

Schedule Model:

```php
public function users() {
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\User');
}
```

If I remove the orWhereHas() it will return a single object. What am I doing wrong here and how can I return a single object based on the requirements above?

Comment: Can you provide some sample data on http://sqlfiddle.com?

Comment: @Pedro is it one to many relationship between users and schedules ?

Comment: show us some data, if its many to many,  show the pivot table data as well

Comment: @AzraarAzward You just pointed me in the right direction, the user relationship was incorrect it should have been belongsTo rather than belongsToMany

Comment: looking at your model relationships it looks like a many to many

Comment: @Pedro i posted the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In User model the correct relationship should be defined as:

```
public function schedules()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Schedule');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In Schedule Model, you need to change the relationship type. i assuming its one to many relationship between users and schedules. in that case change users() to user() and method body as below.

```
public function user() {
   return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\User');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Please try with distinct. For example,

```php
public function schedules()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\Schedule')->distinct();
}
```